# Vanity light installation using an old work box

Tags: light-fixture, light, junction-box, vanity, old-work

I have a vanity light that weighs 5.6 lbs. The old work box I have is rated for 6 lbs. This seems very close to me. Is there something else I should be using?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It also says (specs on Home Depot web site) *not listed for fixture support in ceilings*, so it isn't even a question of 5.6 < 6, but rather "not designed for this purpose at all".

I believe the problem is not "plastic" but rather the wimpy little "swing clamps" - by design then can't support much.

The solution is a box that is actually nailed or screwed into supports. There are plenty of options [like](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RACO-4-in-Round-Ceiling-Fan-Support-Box-For-Old-and-New-Work-2-1-8-in-Deep-with-1-2-in-KO-s-294/203743168):
[image]
For a fan, you really need to make sure it is securely attached to a support (e.g., stud). For a light, there is a bit more leeway as it is (usually) not as heavy and does not have the constant motion/vibration of a fan.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that on the Home Depot website, but my light is going in the wall and not the ceiling. I don’t know if that matters or not.

Comment: The implication, to me, of "not for support in ceiling" is "yes for support in walls". The stress is a bit different, so *probably* OK, particularly for a pretty lightweight fixture. But that being said, a stronger box - or more specifically, a better secured/supported box - wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

With a horizontal fixture you should be fine. I use old work all the time for vanity lights, the one case where I would use caution if the light extends away from the wall more than a few inches, I have mounted carriage lights with old work plastic boxes but if the fixture extends further than that I would be moving to A metal old work box.

Comment: Yea. It sticks out about 9 inches from the wall. Also, it’s between studs. It was previously screwed directly into the drywall by the previous owners. I discovered there was no box behind it while repainting. I took the light fixture off the wall to repaint and it just doesn’t go in anymore.